# NSPredicate to find all of Set A objects not in Set B

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Say I have a `NSManagedObject` called Group and one call User. They both have a to-many relationship to a Car.

I need to figure out what Cars a Group has a relationship to minus the Cars a User has a relationship to.

So say Group 1 has a access to Car A, B, C, and D. User Fred has a access to Car A and B.

Fred can use Car A and B, but I need to create a list of the other Cars he could use from Group 1 that he doesn't already have access to.

I need a `NSPredicate` figure out that Group 1 has a relationship to C and D (A, B, C, and D minus A and B since he already has access to them).

Comment: did you put in the reverse relationships? Seems you could look for a set of cars where _cars.user == nil_

Comment: I think something like ("group == group1 AND user != fred") would work.

Comment: I think @Log139 is right. You want all cars where _group == group1 AND user == nil_

Answer (score 1):

What is with the idea to work with the both sets?

With the function

```
- (void)minusSet:(NSSet *)otherSet
```

you can remove all objects that are in the other set. For your example:

```
[group1AccessSet minusSet:userAccessSet]
```

then you should have all the possible cars in the group1AccessSet :)

The group1AccessSet must be a NSMutableSet!

[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/minusSet%3a)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nielsbot suggestion, I figured out the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"group == %@ AND user != %@", group, user];

NSArray *carList = [Car MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];
```

works.